# What is the isomorphism between E* and Hom(E, M$\times$R)

Tags: vector-bundles

What is the isomorphism between dual vector bundle $E^*$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(E,M\times \mathbb R)$? There is a natural isomorphism on bundle that is $\mathrm{Hom}(E,E')=E^*\otimes E$, therefore I am wondering if I can use this isomorphism to get the result that $E^*$ is isomorphic to $E^*\otimes (M\times\mathbb R)$ and thus isomorphic to $\mathrm{Hom}(E, M\times \mathbb R)$?

Comment: Aside: perhaps it is decent to remark this question was also asked here: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=478220

Answer (score 1):

You are right, $E^*$ is isomorphic to $E^*\otimes (M\times\mathbb R)$. This follows from the fact that $V\otimes\mathbb R\cong V$ for every real vector space $V$.